# Wrong path to repository in org.kohsuke.github Java API for Github

Tags: java, github

This is more a question to the existing package rather then my own code!

Here are the two methods of the package `org.kohsuke.github;`

```java
public GHRepository getRepository(String name) throws IOException {
  String[] tokens = name.split("/");
  if (tokens.length != 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Repository name must be in format owner/repo");
  } else {
    return GHRepository.read(this, tokens[0], tokens[1]);
  }
}
```

```java
static GHRepository read(GitHub root, String owner, String name) throws IOException {
  return (GHRepository)((Requester)root.createRequest().withUrlPath("/repos/" + owner + '/' + name, new String[0])).fetch(GHRepository.class);
}
```

which reads the repository from a URL that it builds likes this:
(given I set up the root as `https://github.com` which I did)
It is making request with the URL:
`https://github.com/repos/OWNER/REPOSITORY_NAME`

It throws an error that repository can't be found. After copying the URL from the exception I see that this is true, because the path it's using `https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY_NAME` points to no directory, but if I remove `/repos` part, the URL is correct. So the way it builds the URL seems to be incorrect.

Am I actually doing something wrong?

Also, I am pretty sure some time ago, the package used to work just fine. Has GitHub changed the structure of the URL?

Comment: The request needs to go to the host `api.github.com`, not `github.com` (or at least, the path format `/repos/OWNER/REPOSITORY_NAME` is valid for `api.github.com`)

Comment: you are right! the host was wrong